# How do I convert this XPath query to LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have some data which looks like:

```
<data>
  <row>
    <v>0.0264</v>
    <v>1073655665.0000</v>  <!-- select this -->
    <v>1073749988.0000</v> 
  </row>
  <row>
    <v>0.0056</v>
    <v>1073655714.0000</v>  <!-- select this -->
    <v>1073751235.0000</v>
  </row>
  <row>
    <v>0.0052</v>
    <v>1073655812.0000</v>  <!-- select this -->
    <v>1073741221.0000</v>
  </row>
</data>
```

How do I select every n'th `<v>` element in each `<row>` using LINQ to XML.

Using XPath I'd just do `/data/row/v[2]` to select every 2nd `<v>` element but I can't seem to figure out how to do this using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var qry = from row in dataNode.Elements("row")
           select row.Elements("v").ElementAt(1);
```

Should do? (untested)